# Websphere custom error page not working

Tags: java, struts2, struts, websphere, custom-error-pages

I have been struggling to get the Websphere custom error page for the errors such as 404 (File not found).

I have added the following to my web.xml under /WEB-INF/

```
<error-page>

    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/html/error404/error404.html</location>

</error-page>
```

and also created a right path /html/error404 and added the error404.html with a warning message to be displayed when user request a file which does not exist.

I have also restarted my WAS and also the browser, but I still get the default error message:

```
Error 404: SRVE0190E: File not found: /xyz.htm
```

and not my custom html error page.

What am I missing here?

Can anyone please help me out, thanks,

Comment: Looks correct - try rebuilding the EAR and redeploy.

Comment: Do I need any struts configuration as well?

Comment: thanks man redeploy did the trick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are likely modifying the web.xml file in the installedApps directory when you should have modified the one in the config directory.

For example, for the IBMUTC app, the web.xml is located at:

```
c:\WAS\config\cells\f11Node01Cell\applications\IBMUTC.ear\deployments\IBMUTC\UTC.war\WEB-INF
```

Use caution because in an ND environment, modifications on a node can be lost when the config is resync'd.  In this case, modify the config on the DMgr itself and then force a resync.  That will push the config change to the nodes.

In all cases, remember to rebuild the EAR and redeploy at some point.